# Recover corrupted wallet due to system crashed

Tags: bitcoind, wallet

My server was crashed suddenly and didn't shut down bitcoin core probably, so now my wallet was corrupted due to it didn't be released. I try to moved the corrupted wallet to a new server but it can't be load:

```
Wallet file verification failed: wallet.dat corrupt, salvage failed
```

I have also tried to use **pywallet** to rescue, but getting this error:

```
ERROR:root:Couldn't open wallet.dat/main. Try quitting Bitcoin and running this again.
```

I suspect that my wallet.dat was totally corrupt so **pywallet** couldn't found *main* . Any help on this please ? Possible to get back my privatekey from wallet.dat please ? Thanks alot.

```
Information:

bitcoin version: v0.18
os: centos7
```

Comment: Is it true you didn't write your private-key down and put that somewhere safe  and you didn't make any backups of your wallet in particular and you also don't have the usual daily backups of all data on your server?

Comment: Ya, didn't do any backup at all. Any ways to recover ?

Answer (score 2):

## Recover corrupted wallet

> Possible to get back my private-key from [corrupted] wallet.dat

I doubt it.

You could put in weeks of effort and not recover anything. By effort I mean learning what tools are available, how to configure and use them and how to evaluate the results. Learning more about the internal structure of wallets etc. Learning about general tools that can recover deleted older versions of files (if you immediately stop using the computer and maybe extract and duplicate the disk) etc.

Most likely you will  be contacted by many scammers offering to recover your wallet or telling you about marvelous people who can recover wallets. It is almost certain that all of them will be trying to trick you out of more money by inventing plausible seeming fees. In this website we see a lot of pleas for help from the victims of recovery scams.

---

## Backups

Most computer users learn early on the importance of backups. Some by seeing other people's good habits, some by seeing other people's disasters and some by making our own disasters.

See Tom Scott - [The Worst Typo I Ever Made](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6NJkWbM1xk)

In the case of Bitcoin, it is essential to make a backup as soon as you create your wallet and again after making any significant changes such as importing a key. This sort of backup needs to be kept somewhere safe from fire, theft or accidental loss.

Comment: Backup is another topic, since that is my testing server so i didn't do any backup for it. Anyway, thanks and appreciate for your answer.